# "Message clipped" newsletters in Gmail

Tags: support, design, newsletter

[image: Message clipped]

Newsletters from SE communities are clipped by Gmail. I always expect to click the `View entire message` whenever I got a newsletter. It seems there is no way to turn off this feature in Gmail.

It is a minor issue and maybe just a Gmail thing. But I think it is true that the newsletters are too long. Maybe there are some better ways to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail clips emails that have a message size larger than 102KB, and hides the full email behind a "View entire message" link. The 102KB limit includes email code only (and not externally referenced images). I'm not sure why they do this, but as you say, there's no way to turn this off. It also happens in mobile Gmail apps and Outlook on iOS and Android.

Having worked on a number of Stack Overflow emails, I'd say the reason why newsletters get clipped is a combination of old (and overly verbose) markup and the sheer length of content. We've been upgrading our emails and will definitely address the verbose code. We'll keep an eye on clipping too, as we address larger emails like newsletters.

Thanks for pointing this out, it reaffirms a problem we should be solving!